# Searching a database (probability problem)

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I can't seem to figure out the Markov chain in (a), disabling me from continuing. Any hints? Also, $\LaTeX$-ifying the question is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

We want to find the transition probabilities. There are $6$ states, one each corresponding to each permutation of $(1,2,3)$.

we can easily write down the transition probabilities from the description of the process. For example, the transition $(1,2,3)\to(1,2,3)$ has probability $p_1$, the transition $(1,2,3)\to(2,1,3)$ has probability $p_2$, the transition $(1,2,3)\to (3,1,2)$ has probability $p_3$, and the other transitions from $(1,2,3)$ have probability $0$.

The other transition probabilities can be written down in the same way. In every case three of them will be $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$, and three of them will be $0$.